# Trying to make a textbox with a simple bit of code but not sure why it gives error

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Rectangle player = new Rectangle();
    private int x=0;
    private int y = 0;
    private System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer timer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();    

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        player.Width = 50;
        player.Height = 50;
        player.Fill = Brushes.Red;
        player.MouseEnter += Player_MouseEnter;
        player.MouseLeave += Player_MouseLeave;
        player.MouseDown += Player_MouseDown;
        myCanvas.Children.Add(player);
    }

    private void Player_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Random rand = new Random(); //Creates the pseudo-random movement
        int a = rand.Next(1, 1001); //With variables a and b
        int b = rand.Next(1, 1001);

        Canvas.SetLeft(player, a);
        Canvas.SetTop(player, b);
    }

    private void Player_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        player.Fill = Brushes.Red;
    }

    private void Player_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        player.Fill = Brushes.Blue;
    }

    public void drawPlayer()//makes it easier to redraw after every click
    {
        Canvas.SetLeft(player, x);
        Canvas.SetTop(player, y);
    }
    private void makeTextBox(//needs something here?)
    {
        TextBox.Text = "POINTS Counter";//Using this later on
    }

}
```

This textbox code I'm guessing needs something in the makeTextBox() for it to make sense. However I cant figure out what as I'm new to wpf, and c# in general. The code simply creates a square that changes colour if someone hovers over it. It then travels a pseudo-random amount on the x and y axis(between 1 and 1000). I now want to add a timer and points system, but can't make the textbox.

I keep getting the error

> CS0120 C# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'TextBox.Text'

If anyone could help that would be great!

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: CS0120  C# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'TextBox.Text'

Comment: You would normally add the textbox in your XAML

Comment: yeah but im adding other parts of code into the textbox after, so I need it in main window for the variables part, klaus

Comment: Just give it a name in XAML: `<TextBox Name="MyTextBox" ...>` and you can access it by this name in your code. You already did this with the player control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You never initialized your Textbox**

for any object-oriented programming language you can't directly access classes unless they are static.

TextBox is not a static class.
I would highly recommend to add the textbox in xaml, as suggested in the comments.
If you do not want to do this for whatever reasons write

```
TextBox MyTextbox = new TextBox();
MyTextBox.Text  = "POINTS Counter";//Using this later on
```

and it should work.

edit: however, even though your error is going to vanish, you will not see your textbox by just doing this.

In order to make it visible, you need to make your container object know about it. I guess you are using some sort of grid in your xaml code, which probably looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="Mytest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:pigc="http://schemas.proleit.com/ic/GUI/Charts"
    xmlns:pic="http://schemas.proleit.com/ic/Core"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Stanlytest"
    xmlns:graph="clr-namespace:Graph"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
<!- Whatever you do here -->

</Grid>
```

Now give your Grid a name, if you haven't (like `<Grid Name="MainGrid"> </Grid>`), then add the textbox as a child to the grid in the xaml.cs (like: `MainGrid.Children.Add(MyTextBox)`.)

I can just advise you again, that although this is a little unfamiliar at first for newcommers (I just recently started learing wpf myself), you should add your objects in xaml.